# how to let pandas show every data row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

when I use pandas and I have a really big rows he makes the rows shorter by telling: `and 543512 more rows`
but I want to write all the rows to a file. How is that possible?

Comment: hi, you can directly write all the data in a csv file  through dataframe function.   df.to_csv('file_name.csv') here df is a dataframe object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a option called `display.max_rows`. Setting it to `None` means unlimited:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

But writing the data to a file can also be done by panda's `to_csv` function or by using `np.savetxt`. This depends on which format you want.

Answer (score 0):

Set pandas option to -1:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```